# How to index and multiply two matrices efficiently?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have two matrices "A", "B", and a data frame "C". They are

```
A <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2) 
colnames(A) <- letters[1:5]

B <- matrix(11:16, nrow = 2)
colnames(B) <- letters[6:8]

C <- data.frame(ix1 = c("a", "d"), ix2 = c("f", "h"))
```

I want to create a vector "vec" with length 2 and values

```
vec[1] = A[,"a"] %*% B[,"f"]
vec[2] = A[,"d"] %*% B[,"h"]
```

This can be done easily with a `for` loop, but it is time consuming when the sizes of "A", "B" and "C" grow. How to do it efficiently?

Comment: What is the use of "C" in your example?

Comment: How is it  done with `for` loop?

Comment: @Pascal he uses it in order to index from `A` and `B`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't see it.

Comment: @Pascal take a look in the answers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I mean, it is not **clearly** used in the question. So it is useless until its use is clearly specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply`:

```
vec = mapply(function(u,v) A[,u]%*%B[,v], c('a','d'), c('f','h'))
```

If you want to use your `data.frame` `C`:

```
vec = mapply(function(u,v) A[,u]%*%B[,v], as.character(C[,1]), as.character(C[,2]))
#  a   d 
# 35 233
```

What really matters is the number of line of `C`, the number of lines in `A` and `B` might not be the bottleneck:

```
v1=rnorm(1000000)
v2=rnorm(1000000)

#> system.time(v1%*%v2)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.00    0.02
```

Answer (score 4):

You can vectorize as follows, but I'm not sure how costly it would be to transpose `A`

```
(vec <- diag(crossprod(A[, as.character(C$ix1)], B[, as.character(C$ix2)])))
## [1]  35 233
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of these cute ways of getting an object printed I'm seeing here a lot recently (also in data.table answers). They obfuscate the intend in a code base and are therefore bad practice. What's wrong with calling `print` explicitly?

Comment: I like it but you do more calculation than necessary ... interesting to know what would be the trade off with `mapply`.

Comment: @Roland what's wrong with it? I saw that a lot in R documentation. Take a look in `?strptime` for example.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Any comparison would depend on input size and the BLAS.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I expressed in my comment why I think it is wrong. (I think in data.table calling `print` explicitly can even be faster. At least, that used to be the case.)